# Reading/Saving lots of data from XML Files C++

Tags: c++, xml, parsing

I am fairly new to C++.
I am tasked to read in a 100k+ line XML file. I was just wondering what is the most efficient way to store this data. So I can parse it later on in my program.

Comment: This question, as stated, makes little sense. Do you want to store the unparsed XML data? What do you want to be efficient, the storage, the parse, or the usage afterwards? Efficient in terms of speed, memory or ease of use?

Comment: I can suggest you to use the boost: look at http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/parsing-xml-with-boost/ and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.xml_parser

Comment: I am using TinyXML to parse the data. Then planning on writing it to an excel file